# Datetime parsing problem resulted in this error: {ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '`' }

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I was trying to read in dates from csv with Pandas. Learn that by reading it in as a datetime object would be much faster compared to reading as a string

This is my code

```
 parse_dates = ['Reqmt Date']
 dateparse = lambda dates: [pd.datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%m.%Y') for d in dates]
 inputWS =  pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', header=0, usecols=headers, dtype=dtypes,
                             parse_dates=parse_dates, date_parser= dateparse)
```

Unfortunately, the interpreter gives me an error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '`'

I did some research and found that the error is due to that my datetime is in the format of    %dd.%mm.%yy  eg 26.02.2016. I believed I have formatted them in the same way I should have formatted them, ie using another date_parser, pd.datetime.strptime() before I read_csv

I just wondering where I could have gone wrong. Or is there need for me to read as string object and then separately convert them ?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) says this method uses `dateutil.parser.parser` as default date parser, which means you have little chance to make parsing better :)

So first recommendation is to run code with `date_parser=None` to see if it works default

If it's not, try to debug it, make a function

```
import dateutil.parser
def parser(dates):
    ret=[]
    for date in dates:
        try:
            ret.append(dateutil.parser.parse(date))
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Failed to parse date '{}': {}".format(date,ex))
    return ret
```

Then run code using `date_parser=parser`
This way you will know exactly which date failed to be parsed